# Can't find module 'crypto-js' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cryptojs

I have a project and this project is displaying "QR code" and then for some reason I have to use a certain encoder function and for that I used this library:

```
Crypto
```

i am trying to use Crypto, but i get this error:

```
Cannot find module 'crypto-js' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

file.tsx:

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

const ENC_KEY =
    '50b3cc356d8f34017b3cce1a021389458b898ae85a816201695d11cb87fa1769';
const IV = '07ed0f192b6d8f36c24bd802e0a52cd4';


/**
 * 
 * @param encryptedQR it should be a hex based string
 * @returns a utf8 based decrypted string
 */
export function decrypt(encryptedQR: string) {
    const key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(ENC_KEY);
    const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(IV);
    const encryptedHex = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(encryptedQR);
    const encrypted = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(encryptedHex);
    const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, {
        iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding,
    });
    return CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(decrypted).trim();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved my problem with this steps:

```
1- npm install crypto-js --save
2- npm install @types/crypto-js
3- 
      from: import { CryptoJS } from ‘crypto-js’;
      to: import * as CryptoJS from ‘crypto-js’;
```

**Or**

```
1- yarn add crypto-js --save
2- yarn add @types/crypto-js
3- 
      from: import { CryptoJS } from ‘crypto-js’;
      to: import * as CryptoJS from ‘crypto-js’;
```

Comment: It is better to install `@types/crypto-js` as a `devDependency`, as it is not required for the app to function on production.

This can be done via `npm install @types/crypto-js --save-dev` or `yarn add --D @types/crypto-js`